# Issue with Maven not finding Jar

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, dependencies

I've managed to get Maven to work in IntelliJ. Recently I've been using the iText library a lot and it's time to build and deploy to tomcat server. Alas, when I looked at the list of dependencies, I see this:

[image]

Now I figured, it must be a server issue, until my colleague ran the **exact same** code and his computer pulled the JAR files down with no problem. I figured I would clear out my `.cache` file next, and force Maven to re-download it's stuff. However, when I came to look at it I found that one does not exist. It isn't present **at all!** This is very odd, and I've been all over google looking for answers, and it hasn't helped.

*System Variables*

**JAVA_HOME** : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25 
**M2_HOME** : C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\maven\apache-maven-3.1.0 
**M2_REPO** : C:.m2\repository 
**PATH Variable includes** : %M2_HOME%\bin

Are there any known issues with Maven that cause this type of behaviour?

*PS*: I am asking after a completely fresh re-install of both IntelliJ and Maven.

Comment: ideally this is not an expected behavior .. can you please check if the required iText jars are available in your local repository i.e M2_REPO after downloading from maven central repo .

Answer (score 0):

Its a good idea to update your local and remote maven repositories after a fresh install. You can do this in your settings for Intellij.

You can push `ctrl + alt + s` to access the settings window.

Under the "Project Settings" header you will find a section for Maven, with a subsection for repositories `Maven -> Repositories`.

You should now see a couple Indexed Maven Repositories. I personally have one for my local m2 repo as well as the `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2`. Select them both and click up the Update button.

The remote repo will take a while to fully update and index, but once it is done it should hopefully be able to find the appropriate jars.

I've had similar problems with different libraries and this solution has worked for me.